# Split text on markup in Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I have the following line of text :

```
<code>stuff</code> and stuff and $\LaTeX$ and <pre class="mermaid">stuff</pre>
```

Using Python, I want to break the markup entities to get the following list:

```
['<code>', 'stuff', '</code>', ' and stuff and $\\LaTeX$ ', '<pre class="mermaid">', 'stuff', '</pre>']
```

So far, I used :

```py
markup = re.compile(r"(<(?P<tag>[a-z]+).*>)(.*?)(<\/(?P=tag)>)")
text = '<code>stuff</code> and stuff and $\LaTeX$ and <pre class="mermaid">stuff</pre>'
words = re.split(markup, text)
```

but it yields :

```
['<code>', 'code', 'stuff', '</code>', ' and stuff and $\\LaTeX$ ', '<pre class="mermaid">', 'pre', 'stuff', '</pre>']
```

The problem is the `(?P=tag)` group is added to the list because it's captured. I capture it only to get the closest closing tag.

How could I get rid of it in the resulting list, assuming the code processes only one single line at a time ?

Comment: It would be easier to use `re.finditer` and then write a RegEx to define what you consider one "token" rather than using `re.split` which requires you to write an ugly RegEx for the delimiters.

Comment: The purpose of the list is to apply post-processing on plain text and on some tags, while discarding some other tags, `re.finditer` only returns matches and doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Maybe even [`re.findall(r"<[^>]*>|[^<]+", text)`](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwEEX3@YohFNqq6MJtmi/o0oVQWwjNFAPNg0lEBf891oC7@@DcG97p7t05Z2ODpwSEjCV8JeigFrPXKGN6LIs4FQ3KaShBUdWtVxe8VsWIQAjzqmLsuEWyymj@h7dK1ow9Pem4LRMeF@O0WteGuBgmOe7kZ5jEuOcH@L23jAUyLjWFaHP@Ag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx is not suitable for parsing HTML. However it typically suffices for tokenization. Using `re.finditer`, tokenization becomes a one-liner:

```py
list(map(lambda x: x.group(0), re.finditer(r"(?:<(?:.*?>)?)|[^<]+", s)))
```

Explanation:

- Use only noncapturing groups `(?:...)`; we don't need specific captures here.
- Match either a "tag" `<(?:.*?>)?` (may be invalid (just `<` sign), recognized only by its opening `<`, goes until `>`) or plaintext `[^<]+`.

This handles your test case

```py
s = '<code>stuff</code> and stuff and $\LaTeX$ and <pre class="mermaid">stuff</pre>'
```

correctly, producing

```py
['<code>', 'stuff', '</code>', ' and stuff and $\\LaTeX$ and ', '<pre class="mermaid">', 'stuff', '</pre>']
```

Note however that a full-blown HTML tokenizer would need a much more complex regular grammar to handle e.g. attributes like `onclick = "console.log(1 < 2)"` properly. You'd be better off using an off-the-shelf library to do the markup parsing (or even just tokenization) for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `xml` which is a module designed for `xml files` which is synonymous to `html`.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

text = '<code>stuff</code> and stuff and $\LaTeX$ and <pre class="mermaid">stuff</pre>'

root = ET.fromstring(f'<root>{text}</root>')

result = []

for element in root:
    if element.tag:
        result.append(f'<{element.tag}>')
    if element.text:
        result.extend(element.text.split())
    if element.tail:
        result.append(element.tail)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = r'<code>stuff</code> and stuff and $\LaTeX$ and <pre class="mermaid">stuff</pre>'

l = []

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == ">":
        l[-1] += s[i]
        l.append("")
    elif s[i] == "<":
        l.append("")
        l[-1] += s[i]
    else:
        l[-1] += s[i]
        
l.pop()
print(l)
```

Output: `['<code>', 'stuff', '</code>', ' and stuff and $\\LaTeX$ and ', '<pre class="mermaid">', 'stuff', '</pre>']`